# why is there a concrete pole in my wall?

Tags: concrete, walls, interior, pole

I broke open a section of wall I'd like to remove and there is a concrete pole inside!? Is this some kind of load bearing device? How can I know if I can remove it?

Thanks

Comment: That has to be a structural column. You need to get the blueprints for the house and talk to an engineer. It is unlikely that you can remove the column without extensive redesign, demolition and installation of new supports and maybe something like a steel I-beam, if at all.

Comment: Sometimes designers put that kind of columns to strenghten the wall to help sustain planar stiffness and/or to deliver loads from the roof to foundation. Definately not to be demolished. DMoore suggested to overcome it by adding a beam, but I guess it's easier to leave it alone and find another solution to Your house remodel.

Answer (score 2):

Either it is a load bearing pole or someone who built the post was just practicing their pole making skills.  You can remove it when you offset the load to another part of your house.  Usually this would involve putting up an overhead beam and 1-2 poles to hold that.  This is very specific to your house and taking out a concrete pole will definitely involve an engineer.